# Raster calculator not performing sum

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have multiple rasters, which I reclassed to values from 0 to 10.

I weighted those rasters in "raster calculator" with my weight values and I obtained the correct values for each raster.
Then I used the following formula in raster calculator:

`"raster1" + "raster2" + "raster3" + so on`

When I try to sum all these weighted rasters in raster calculator, I get the following values and no raster shows up:
max: 3.400282e+38,
min: -3.400282e+38

My sum values should be:
max: 26,25
min: 4,15

All my rasters are in the same PCS and GCS. I tried to mix various extent settings but it didn't worked.

Comment: it's not a symbology issue and the values are not correct. It returned me no raster, just empty screen and wrong values. I need a raster made of all summed weighted_rasters to use for my suitability analysis.

Comment: Do you have nodata set in your rasters? Is it perhaps `-3.400282e+38`?

Comment: Use [Cell Statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/cell-statistics.htm), with Overlay statistic = Sum and Ignore NoData = True (Checked).

Comment: Thanks. I did it this way

Comment: Do you mean that your problem is solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have NoData values overlapping with your data values.

Use the [Cell Statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/cell-statistics.htm) tool, with the following parameters:

- Overlay statistic = Sum
- Ignore NoData = True (Checked)